# UITableviewcell set property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need to set the properties in uitableviewcell. The following code is written as I do.

myTableViewCell.h

```
@interface myTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *row;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *section;
```

myTableViewCell.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    NSLog(@"%@",_row);

}
return self;
```

}

myTableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[myTableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
```

Result row = nill. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are logging `_row` before you set it. It doesn't get set until after the call to `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Comment: Better yet, they should be `NSUInteger` properties.